# php: dynamically access an element in array, which is object property

Tags: php

i have an array as object property, **$obj->_image = ['size' => '10'];** and want to access it dynamically, like:  (of course object initialized and exists, just skipped to make post shorter. **print $obj->_image['size']** works like it should.)

```
$obj->get('image','size');

public function get($item,$element = '') {

if (!empty($element)) $element = "['$element']";
    $item = "_$item$element";

return $this->$item;
}
```

but get: Undefined property: obj::$_image['size']

tryed with {}, $$ - but looks like i am missing something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to access a property that is an array, so you can't do it like you are doing it. Try this

```
class a
{

    private $_image = array("size" => 10);

    public function get($item, $element = '')
    {
        $prop = "_$item";
        if (property_exists(__CLASS__, $prop))
        {
            if (empty($element))
            {
                return $this->{$prop};
            }
            if(array_key_exists($element, $this->{$prop})){
                return $this->{$prop}[$element];
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("'$item' or '$element' don't exist");
    }

}

$a = new a;
echo $a->get("image", "size");
```

The problem with your code is that your property is an array, so you first need to access the array `$this->{"_$prop"}` and then the element within the array `$this->{"_$prop"}[$el]`

Comment: yes, already done this style, now just looking for "nicer" way (if it exists of course).

Comment: there is no `nicer` way. but you can also try implementin `ArrayAccess` in your class and accessing your properties like in an array, `$this["_image"]` for example. are your code working or you keep getting the same error of `Undefined property: obj::$_image['size'] `?

Comment: with [] moved out of variable (your way) - it works, if i try put it inside like in initial "nice" code - nope, same error.